# Angular Jasmine UI router inject resolve value into test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-ui-router, karma-runner

In my Angular app, UI router resolves a promise into the controller. When trying to test this controller, Karma is complaining about an unknown provider. How do I inject a fake object into the test to represent this resolve object.

My app's code looks something like:

```
angular.module('myapp')
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('tab.name', {
        ...
        resolve: {
            allTemplates: function(Templates) {
                return Templates.all().then(function(templates) {
                    return templates;
                });
            }
        }
    })
})
.controller('QueriesCtrl', function(allTemplates, UserQuery) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.queries = allTemplates;
    vm.goToUrl = function(index, data) {
        var processedUrl = UserQuery.process(data, vm.queryTyped[index]);
        UserQuery.goToUrl(processedUrl);
    };
});
```

When trying to run tests I get the error

```
Unknown provider: allTemplatesProvider <- allTemplates <- QueriesCtrl
```

I've tried creating a spy and injecting it, but this does not work. Here's my test at the moment:

```
describe('Unit: queriesCtrl', function() {
    var controller,
        scope,
        UserQuery;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('myapp');
        inject(function($injector) {
            UserQuery = $injector.get('UserQuery');
            allTemplates = jasmine.createSpyObj('allTemplates', [{a:1}, {a:2}, {b:3}]);
        });
    });

    describe('goToUrl', function() {
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('QueriesCtrl as ctrl', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        }));
        it('should call UserQuery.process()', function() {
            spyOn(UserQuery, 'process');
            scope.ctrl.goToUrl();
            expect(UserQuery.process).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since there is no route involved in unit test you would have to inject the `allTemplates` as a normal object with `$controller` function. Can you try:

```
controller = $controller('QueriesCtrl as ctrl', {
                '$scope': scope,
                 'allTemplates':allTemplates 
            });
```

Else you can use the `$provide` API to create a dummy service.

```
 module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value("allTemplates", {[{a:1}, {a:2}, {b:3}]});
```

Do it first thing in your `beforEach` block.

Comment: @ Chandermani, I am new to mocha-Chai , could please help out with similar issue posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606056/mocha-chai-test-case-for-angular-configuration-file