# Unit Testing UI Router With Resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test for my `ui-router` with uses `resolve`.

Router.js

```
define(['module', 'require'], function(module, require) {
    'use strict';

    var Router = function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/shopping');

        $stateProvider
            .state('shopping', {
                url: '/shopping',
                templateUrl: 'app/shopping.html',
                resolve:{
                    userFactory : 'UserFactory',
                    checkAccess:function(userFactory){
                        return userFactory.checkUser();
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('products', {
                url: '/products',
                templateUrl: 'app/products.html',
                resolve:{
                    userFactory : 'UserFactory',
                    checkAccess:function(userFactory){
                        return userFactory.checkUser();
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('notAuth', {
                url: '/notAuth',
                templateUrl: 'app/unauthorised.html'
            });
    };

    module.exports = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', Router];
});
```

Within userFactory.checkUser(); i essentially check the users' rights, and redirect either to the templateUrl, or perform a:

```
$state.go('notAuth');
```

My currect .spec.js:

```
define(['require', 'angular-mocks', 'angular-ui-router', 'app/router'], function (require) {
    'use strict';
    describe('myApp/myState', function() {

        var $rootScope, $state, $injector, myServiceMock, $httpBackend, state = 'shopping';

        var mockResponse = {
            "access": true
        }

        var angular = require('angular');
        var myRouter = require('app/router');

        beforeEach(module('ui.router'));

        beforeEach(function() {

            module(myRouter, function($provide) {
                $provide.value('userFactory', myServiceMock = {});
            });

            inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_, _$injector_, $templateCache, _$httpBackend_) {
                $rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
                $state = _$state_;
                $injector = _$injector_;
                $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
                $rootScope.$digest();
            })
        });

        it('should transition to shopping', inject(function($state,$rootScope){
            $state.transitionTo('shopping');
            $rootScope.$apply();
            expect($state.current.name).toBe('shopping');
        }));

        it('should resolve data', function() {
            myServiceMock.checkUser = jasmine.createSpy('checkUser').and.returnValue(mockResponse);
            // earlier than jasmine 2.0, replace "and.returnValue" with "andReturn"

            $state.go(state);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect($state.current.name).toBe(state);
        });
    });
});
```

With the above test, i get the following errors:

```
Information:  myApp/myState
Information:    should transition to shopping   Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Information:    Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
Information:    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Information:    should resolve data Expected '' to be 'shopping'.
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there are a few things happening here.  First, you're digesting too many times.  That's the "10 $digest() iterations reached" message.  To fix that one, you should remove the `$rootScope.$digest()` from the end of your inject function.

I think the actual failing test part is because you're not resolving your `checkAccess` resolve that you've configured in your route.  Try adding `$provide.value('checkAccess', function() {return true;});` to your `$provide.value` setup. That should allow checkAccess to resolve in your route, which will then allow the route to complete the state transition.

I found my answer to a similar question here: [Angular Jasmine UI router inject resolve value into test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557749/angular-jasmine-ui-router-inject-resolve-value-into-test)